# D3 on Angular: Changing data object does not refresh chart

Tags: angularjs, d3.js

I have a button that changes data

```
$scope.changeData = function(){
    $scope.myData = [10, 80, Math.floor((Math.random()*30)+1)];
}
```

and a directive which uses this data.

```
<bars-chart chart-data="myData"></bars-chart>
```

I thought there was supposed to be some 2-way binding, and it does show up on the view if I dump the value, but it doesn't call the link function again.

Am I doing something wrong here?
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwWqpa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because d3 is not angular, you need to set a watcher to make this work. Embed all the logic in your link function within a watcher, like this:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
  scope.$watch(function(){
    // all logic here
  });
}
```

The only problem now is that this will keep appending new charts, instead of replacing the current one, but this is probably because you use `chart.append("div")`. I think there's a different function in d3 you should use to replace instead of append.

Alternatively, you could put the creation logic outside of the watcher, and write extra code for updating the chart within the watcher.